# Использование прямой и косвенной речи

Tags: грамотная-речь, прямая-речь

Можно ли использовать прямую речь в предложениях следующего типа:

***Всё вокруг говорило, нет, всё кричало само за себя: "Убирайся отсюда подальше".***

Или всё же текст после двоеточия — не прямая речь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А в чем вообще вопрос? Он вообще теоретический или практический?

Если фраза написана так, как вы её приводите, то она является (по мысли автора по крайней мере) прямой речью и оформлена как прямая речь. Это ничему нее противоречит и вполне логично.

Если же вы и есть автор и думаете, как такую конструкцию оформить: с двоеточием или без, то тут дело сложнее. Можно допустить, что слова в кавычках не являются прямой речью (цитата), или же прямой речью, не требующей двоеточия (прямая речь как член предложения), но в вашем случае это вызовет массу вопросов. 
Так что лучше всё-таки все оформить именно так, как у вас есть.

Ксть, правда один пограничный случай, когда (вроде бы) и речь прямая, и не член предложения, и не цитата, а двоеточие на практике не ставится.

> Солдат сорвал папаху и поднял ее над головой. Кое-кто закричал «ура!», 
>   но жидко, вразброд.

Сразу скажу, что это случай спорный, искать на него правила и разбираться в них в данной теме я не буду, но формально он дает некоторые основания для отступления от общего правила. Но в любом случае такое возможно, видимо, только при очень короткой реплике героя/персонажа. У вас-то целая фраза, вполне законченная...

Из всего этого могу сделать только одну рекомендацию. Считайте прямой речью - и оформляйте соответственно.

Увидел в другом ответе...

> Поэтому надо разделять понятия прямая речь и оформление по образцу прямой речи.

Это отчасти верно, но представляет лишь теоретический интерес. Вас только запутает, ибо для нужд правописания такое разграничение никакой ценности не представляет. Имеет смысл разграничивать то, что оформляется по-разному, а тут-то как раз наоборот, скорее надо объединить в одно понятие "прямой речи" - по принципу общности орфографического и пунктуационного оформления.

Answer (score 2):

Текст после двоеточия — не прямая речь? Речь прямая, но её принадлежность неопределённа.

Прямая речь не выделяется кавычками, если нет точного указания, кому она принадлежит (прямая речь вводится безличным или неопределенно-личным предложением):

Недаром говорится: дело мастера боится (посл.); Про него говорили: строгий, но справедливый.

(Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В.В. Лопатина. — М.: Эксмо, 2006.)

*Всё кричало: убирайся отсюда.*

Answer (score 1):

Это классический вариант прямой речи как по смыслу, так и по оформлению:

**Всё вокруг говорило, нет, всё кричало само за себя: "Убирайся отсюда подальше".**

1) В ПАС прямая речь **определяется следующим образом**:

Прямая речь, т. е. речь **другого лица**, включенная в авторский текст и воспроизведенная дословно. [Лопатин. Знаки препинания при прямой речи](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)

2) Розенталь определяет **прямую речь как чужую**, но при этом по тем же правилам он оформляет **внутреннюю речь** (невысказанные мысли) и даже **звуки.**  [§ 47. Оформление прямой речи](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=155#pp155)

3) **Чужая речь, переданная в форме придаточного предложения, называется косвенной речью.**
Первая, главная часть предложения в этом случае представляет собой слова автора, а вторая – косвенную речь. Обратите внимание: слова автора стоят перед косвенной речью и отделяются от нее запятой. Этот способ передачи чужой речи, в отличие от прямой речи, сохраняет содержание чужого высказывания, но не сохраняет его форму и интонацию. [ЧУЖАЯ РЕЧЬ И СПОСОБЫ ЕЕ ПЕРЕДАЧИ | gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_192)

4) В то же время прямая речь, соответствующая определению, то есть чужая речь, может оформляться **упрощенно, без двоеточия**, но с кавычками, например:  С криком "Убирайтесь отсюда!" они пробежали дальше.

Поэтому надо различать такие понятия, как **прямая речь и способы передачи прямой речи:** классическое оформление, косвенная речь, упрощенное оформление (в виде члена предложения) и т.д.